# Data type format are not recognized when exporting DataGridView to Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, firebird

My program has the following features:

- Visual Studio 2015
- db.gdb running under Firebird 3.0
- .Net Framework 4.6 with dataset

**References:**

- FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient release 7.10.1.0
- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel release 12.0.0.0

**1. Dates**

When I export a DataGridView to Excel (Office 2007) release 12, I meet the following problems:

in the DataGridView, the `Date` is in italian format 03/06/2022 (dd/MM/yyyy), June 3rd 2022 while in Excel it is 06/03/2022. This date for me is March 6th 2022.
This date is exported to Excel as a date while 31/05/2022 (in italian May 31th 2022) is not recognized and so exported as text.

**2. Numbers**

The number e.g. 27 is well exported as a number, while 27,50 is not recognized and so exported as text.

*Note:*
My Region Area is set to Italy and Italian.
My date format is dd/MM/yyyy
My decimal separator is: , (comma)

I tried to fix it but with no success.
I need a hint because I do not know what to do.

Been writing code since 2005 to 2021, same program but with db.mdb Visual Studio .NET 2.0,Dataset and all was working. No problems at all. Never.

Few lines of code:

The `Date` is in Double format.

```
Imports ExcelAPP = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

'This shows the column as Date
Private startDate As New Date(1899, 12, 30)
Private Sub DTBollePagateDataGridView_CellFormatting(ByVal sender 
As Object, ByVal e As 
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles 
DTBOLLEPAGATEDataGridView.CellFormatting

Try

If Me.DTBOLLEPAGATEDataGridView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText 
= "DATA" Then

If e.Value Is DBNull.Value Then Exit Sub
If e.Value IsNot Nothing Then e.Value = 
startDate.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(e.Value)).ToShortDateString

End If

Catch ex As Exception

Dim lNewVariable2 As String = "mailto:?subject=Invio Dati&body= 
{0}{1}{2}"
        
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String.Format(lNewVariable2, 
ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.StackTrace))

End Try
End Sub

'Export to Excel
'Impostazione dei formati (This doesn't work)
'FogliodiLavoro.Range("D1:D200").NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and focus on one and one problem only (e.g. only dates, or only numbers), and after resolving the first problem, ask a new question about the second problem (if the solution doesn't turn out to be the same). Also, please reconsider your tags. Your problem is unlikely to have to do with Visual Studio 2015, and more likely to do with the language and libraries you're using. It sounds to me like you're exporting dates (and possibly numbers) as Strings, while the cell has the wrong datetime format pattern.

Comment: The following may be useful: [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5), [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK), [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML), [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus).

Comment: You could try using the [DateTime.ToOADate Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate) to get the Double which represents the datetime in Excel, then set the formatting on the range to show as a date.

Comment: Well, honestly based on your description of the problem, my guess is most of these issues are simply because your treating dates and numbers as strings.  Use the correct data types for the data you're working with and most of these problems are going to simply vanish.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you. Very appreciated. When exporting 13/06/2022 becomes 06/13/2022 and I do not the reason why. Maybe the Firebird client...My solution is: NOT Cellformatting and  FogliodiLavoro.Range("D1:D200").NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" This works as Andrew Morton suggested.

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be related to Firebird, it has everything to do with how you are creating and populating your Excel file.